# How do I override the base price against Custom option Pricing?

Tags: magento, view, product, catalog

Hi this was a question from magento forum on their site.. However I am looking for the same thing for a while, could any answer this ?

***I need the exact area in which Magento adds Base price and Custom option price ***

> I have been looking across these forums so many apologies if this is a
>   duplicate, but I am having a lot of trouble with the custom option
>   pricing on front-end not being absolute, but adding itself onto the
>   base price of the product.
>
> I have been looking at a few modules, which I am happy to purchase, if
>   easy to implement, but there are quite a few that are going around.
>
> Attached are some images if anyone has a solution.
>
> The base price on the product (is a product with many different custom
>   options, could be size options also) is £7.32, which is fine as the
>   page states ‘From £7.32’
>
> However, there are a few options selectable, which rather than show
>   (+) and ultimately add to the base price, should show the actual price
>   and not onto of the base price.
>
> So Rhynogrip 70 x 198 price is actually £48.96, however when selected
>   it adds this to the £7.32, rather than replace it. The attached all
>   show this.
>
> If anyone could help that would be great!
>
> Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you set the price of Rhinogrip 70x198 to 48.96 - 7.32 because that is what MAgento expects.

Comment: So it doesn't replaces the base price with custom price, are you sure we need to deduct the value instead ?

Comment: Yes I am sure if we are talking about the associated products of a configured product.Magento will always + or - the difference between the base price of the configurable and the price you enter in the `Super product attributes configuration`. So leave the simple price of Rhinogrip as 48.96 but make the `Super product attributes configuration` price variance +41.64

Comment: while handling the simple product with custom options ?

Comment: I think price deduction is the correct way, however I would like to check the operation where magento + or - the base price with custom option price